# Modify List<T> using Linq to Average rows with matching designator

Tags: c#, linq

I have a .csv file wherein each row of data represents a part and its associated parameters. e.g. Name, Y-Position, etc.
I have defined a class to represent each part and have already parsed the .csv into `List<Part> parts`

However, the CSV file contains multiple rows with the same Name. I want to reduce `List<Part> parts` combining rows of same Name and averaging Y-Position.

Input: .csv

```
Name,XPosition,YPosition
A,10,1
B,10,4
C,10,3
C,10,5
D,12,6
D,12,8
```

I've created `List<Part> parts` from this data.

Desired output: `List<Parts> part` containing:

```
Part { Name="A", YPosition=1 },
Part { Name="B", YPosition=4 },
Part { Name="C", YPosition=4 },
Part { Name="D", YPosition=7 }
```

I've tried:

```
List<Part> parts = parts
.GroupBy(p => p.Name)
.Select(g => new Part()
{
    Name = g.Key, 
    YPosition = g.Average(p => p.YPosition)
}
foreach (Part g in parts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(g.Name + "," + g.XPosition + "," + g.YPosition);
}
```

But XPosition is not passed to parts...

Comment: Title asks for modifying list but body of the post says nothing about it... Could you please [edit] post to align those parts?

Comment: You say you want to averyage `YPosition` but you do not say what you want to do with the multiple `XPosition` values you have from the parts with the same name - not in your question, not in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are not selecting the XPosition when you are getting the other information from the Part. I have added a select statement below to grab the first value of the XPosition from the Part. I ran this snippet of code and was getting the desired XPosition. Hopefully that solves your problem.

```
List<Part> parts = parts
.GroupBy(p => p.Name)
.Select(g => new Part()
{
    Name = g.Key, 
    XPosition = g.Select(p => p.XPosition).FirstOrDefault(),
    YPosition = g.Average(p => p.YPosition)
}
```